# Facebook Re-Authentication not working as intended

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-authentication

I have an app that I'd like to use Facebook's re-authentication feature along with FB login for access to our site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/). This is supposed to require the user to input their FB password in order to access our site. When the login button is clicked, the FB dialog pops up fine and asks the person to reenter their password.

However, for users that have in the past given permission to the app (have logged in successfully in the past) we found that if they just closes that dialog window, they are granted access as if the re-auth method didn't exist at all. This should throw an error asking the person to re-enter their password in the box.

Of note, when the dialog box pops up, there is already an access token in the URL before the user enters their password. I suspect that the app is accepting this old access token, which is why the user gets access even if they close the window.

Any ideas?